# Required Atrribute, how to load error message from database? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to use Error message string from the database as the Required Error Message?

For the Required validation attribute, in my Address Model, I want to use the error message stored in my database, and not hard code it. It has be from a database and not a resx file.

In my current code I'm using a SSPResourceManager class to call the database based on the ErrorMessageResourceName. This isn't working for depedency injection reasons. is there another approach.

**Current Code**

Model

```
public abstract class AddressVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SSPResourceManager), ErrorMessageResourceName = "SSP_Validation_Required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here I'm looking for a static property "SSP_Validation_Required" from the SSPResourceManager class

SSPResourceManager class

```
 public class SSPResourceManager
 {
    private static ITranslationService _translationService = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ITranslationService>();

    private static string _languageCode = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LanguageCode"].ToString();

    public static string SSP_Validation_Required
    {
        get
        {
             // call database and retrive the correct error string 
            return _translationService.Read("SSP_Validation_Required", "SSP", _languageCode); 
        }
    }
}
```

this approach isn't working, as I'm having problem injecting Itranslation dependecy.

Is there another approach to loading error message from database and using in the required attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not easy or straight-forward. The default DataAnnotationValidationProvider only supports resource files or static classes. I was able to find a solution for you here: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/09/04/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-upgraded.aspx, but like I said, you've got a bit of work cut out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve it is by creating a new class based on `RequiredAttribute`

```
public class ResourceErrorMessage : RequiredAttribute
{
     public ResourceErrorMessage(string resourceKey): base()
     {
           this.ErrorMessage = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITranslationService>().Translate(ResourceKey, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
     }  
}
```

Create a `CustomMetadataProvider` base on `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`

```
 public class CustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
    {
        protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
                                 IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
                                 Type containerType,
                                 Func<object> modelAccessor,
                                 Type modelType,
                                 string propertyName)
            {
                var data = base.CreateMetadata(attributes,
                                          containerType,
                                         modelAccessor,
                                         modelType,
                                         propertyName);

                var resourceErrorMessage = attributes
                            .SingleOrDefault(a => typeof(ResourceErrorMessage) == a.GetType());
                if (resourceErrorMessage != null) data.AdditionalValues
                            .Add("ResourceErrorMessage", ((ResourceErrorMessage)resourceErrorMessage).ResourceKey);

                return data;
            }
        }
```

In `global.asax Application_Start()` add
`ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomMetadataProvider()`;
and use it on your model

```
public class TestModel
{
  [ResourceErrorMessage("somestring")]
  public int TextAttribute{ set; get; }
}
```